# Nestjs triggering a Shutdown and Reboot

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I know about the shutdown hooks and lifecycle events, but how do I call them?
Lets say the controller receives a shutdown call from the UI.
How would I call a shutdown event to trigger a nestjs shutdown?
How would I call a reboot event to trigger a nestjs reboot?

Example:

```
@SubscribeMessage('systemChange')
serverUpdate(@MessageBody() data: any): any{
    if(data === 'shutdown') {
       Make Call To Shutdown NestJs Server
    } else if (data === 'reboot') {
       Make Call To Reboot NestJs Server
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code for context? Speaking in abstract terms is a lot harder.

Comment: Couple of questions: what platform are you on? Why do you want to initiate a shutdown from the client side instead of from direct access to the server?

Comment: I’m not looking to shutdown or reboot the computer, just the nestjs server.  Mainly so I can install updates.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/923 here is some relevant answers, might help